# How can a user post at Twitter through rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**What I want** - users of the rails app can post at their twitter account through the app

**What I have done so far** - 
I am using Devise and Twitter gems, and have filled all the twitter details at /initializers/twitter.rb file

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ""
  config.consumer_secret = ""
  config.oauth_token = ""
  config.oauth_token_secret = ""
end
```

now I can create a controller "post_twitter" with index action and a view but I am not sure, how to do the integration with this controller/view and twitter ?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a multi-user app, then you won't want to set `config.oauth_token` & `config.oauth_token_secret` in the initializer, since that would be applied for each user.

Comment: Check out [Thread Safety](https://github.com/sferik/twitter#thread-safety) for more details on how to handle `config.oauth_token` & `config.oauth_token_secret`.

Comment: @JamesChevalier - James, thanks,  I am still unsure how to get users :oauth_token and :oauth_token_secret ? if I can get that, I think I should be able to do the rest

Comment: If you search around for "twitter gem oauth" you should find some useful stuff. Basically, you're using the `oauth` gem to get authorization done. [This](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/twitter-oauth-and-ruby-on-rails-integrated-cookbook-style-in-the-console-updated-for-twitter-1-0/) doesn't seem too bad...

Answer (score 3):

In your controller you could use the `Twitter` class, this is what I have done

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
    #code
end
```

Make sure you enable POST privileges to your Twitter app, and if the Twitter update fails it  should give you an error message.

Comment: Please stop adding "HTH" to every post. [Signatures and taglines are not allowed here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: sorry, will not use again :)

Comment: @sameera207 - Thanks HTH, is it possible you can share the full code with me in some way ? what is confusing me is, how to make multiple users of the app post in their respective twitter accounts. They do have to "signup" somehow to their account, right ?

Comment: @sameera207 - alright now I am able to make the tweets! but still how to make each user post in their accounts (right now the tweets are being sent to only one account who oauth_token I have filled)

Comment: I think this section of the documentation will help you https://github.com/sferik/twitter#thread-safety

Comment: @sameera207 - thanks, but I am still unsure how to get users  :oauth_token and  :oauth_token_secret ? if I can get that, I think I should be able to do the rest :)

Comment: @iCyborg think you need to use oauth for storing the user authentication details.

Comment: I think the concept is to post to your twitter time line. Say if you create a twitter app called 'A', your rails app could post anything to the time line of 'A'. However I dont think you can post to someone elses time line. But I think you should be able to DM them. (this is how I think, I might be wrong). Coz having having individual :oauth_token, :oauth_token_secre seems un-logical to me :)